# pandas groupby X,Y and select last week of X1 and X2 (which have diff frequency)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a a DataFrame that looks like this(generally):

> ```
> time      source   id
> 5-4-2014    A       1
> 5-4-2014    A       1
> 5-5-2014    A       1
> ...
> 4-12-2013   B       12
> 4-12-2013   B       12
> 4-12-2013   B       12
> ...
> ```

- Source A is frequency about 2/day,
- Source B is frequency greater.

I would like to group-by source and id; and than select the last week of data for each.

I tried a quick tail(20), but for my purposes(to subtract the histograms(pmf)) of each patients last week, Id like to be more precise.

How do I get the last week of an index?

Comment: What do you mean with 'last week'? Just the last date in that group?

Comment: No, I mean the range of rows from the last date(for a group), that span one week of time (indexed).  (Sorry for the confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have such a dataframe:

```
In [50]: s="""time      source   id
    ...: 4-25-2014    A       1
    ...: 5-4-2014    A       1
    ...: 5-5-2014    A       1
    ...: 4-2-2013   B       12
    ...: 4-6-2013   B       12
    ...: 4-11-2013   B       12
    ...: 4-12-2013   B       12
    ...: 4-12-2013   B       12"""

In [51]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s+")

In [52]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
        time source  id
0 2014-04-25      A   1
1 2014-05-04      A   1
2 2014-05-05      A   1
3 2013-04-02      B  12
4 2013-04-06      B  12
5 2013-04-11      B  12
6 2013-04-12      B  12
7 2013-04-12      B  12
```

Then you can select the rows you want in an apply call on the grouped object:

```
In [57]: g = df.groupby(['source', 'id'])

In [58]: g.apply(lambda x : x[x['time'] > (x['time'].iloc[-1] - dt.timedelta(7))])
Out[58]: 
                  time source  id
source id                        
A      1  1 2014-05-04      A   1
          2 2014-05-05      A   1
B      12 4 2013-04-06      B  12
          5 2013-04-11      B  12
          6 2013-04-12      B  12
          7 2013-04-12      B  12
```

Comment: Although, havent checked it yet; it looks right. Thanks!  I was running pandas .10 (no .iloc support), upgraded to .14 and getting a pandas.algos.ensure error (float nan to int..)  Ill have to uninstall pandas and maybe try to install a lower version... although this is not looking promising.  any advice ?

Comment: If you can't upgrade or don't solve the issue you have with 0.14, you can try to use `ix` instead of `iloc`